# How to annotate code with cache miss ratio (instead of just cache hits or misses) using perf?

Tags: performance, perf

I am trying to look for areas of code with higher than average cache misses, to identify areas to improve. I am using perf, and collecting events. I can see how I can look at overall cache hit ratios using `perf stat`, and I can use `perf annotate` to annotate my source code with the number of cache hits/misses, but not a ratio.

There must be some way to do this, but I cannot seem to find it anywhere.

I've read through the documentation of perf, and searched online... but have ended up stumped. I am sure I have just missed something obvious.